# Nested RecycleView with Firebase this error "Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap" when I insert data using push()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This is the code for the nested recycler view.
If I add data using the `push()` method, i get the Nested RecycleView with Firebase this error:

> Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

```
AlertDialog dialog;
IFirebaseLoadListener iFirebaseLoadListener;

RecyclerView my_recycler_view;
DatabaseReference myData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myData= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyData");
    dialog= new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).build();

    iFirebaseLoadListener = this;

    // view
    my_recycler_view= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

 load data
    getFirebaseData();
}

private void getFirebaseData() {
    dialog.show();
    myData.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<itemGroup> itemGroups= new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot groupSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                itemGroup itemGroup= new itemGroup();

///
Firebase instance code
///
                itemGroup.setHeaderTitle(groupSnapshot.child("headerTitle").getValue(true).toString());
                GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<itemData>> genericTypeIndicator= new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<itemData>>(){} ;
                itemGroup.setListItem(groupSnapshot.child("listItem").child(key).getValue(genericTypeIndicator));
                itemGroups.add(itemGroup);


            }
            iFirebaseLoadListener.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(itemGroups);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            iFirebaseLoadListener.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<itemGroup> itemGroupList) {

    MyItemGroupAdapter adapter = new MyItemGroupAdapter(this,itemGroupList);
    my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onFirebaseLoadFailed(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.dismiss();

}
```

}

```
 public class itemData {

private String name ,image;

public itemData() {
}

public itemData(String name, String image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}

public class itemGroup {
private String headerTitle;
private ArrayList<itemData> listItem;

public itemGroup() {
}

public itemGroup(String headerTitle, ArrayList<itemData> listItem) {
    this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
    this.listItem = listItem;
}

public String getHeaderTitle() {
    return headerTitle;
}

public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
    this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
}

public ArrayList<itemData> getListItem() {
    return listItem;
}

public void setListItem(ArrayList<itemData> listItem) {
    this.listItem = listItem;
}
```

}

```
 public class MyItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<itemData> itemDataList;

public MyItemAdapter(Context context, List<itemData> itemDataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemDataList = itemDataList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

    myViewHolder.txt_item_titles.setText(itemDataList.get(i).getName());
    Picasso.get().load(itemDataList.get(i).getImage()).into(myViewHolder.img_item);

    myViewHolder.setiItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClickListener(View view, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+ itemDataList.get(i).getName(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (itemDataList != null ? itemDataList.size() : 0);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    TextView txt_item_titles;
    ImageView img_item;

    IItemClickListener iItemClickListener;

    public void setiItemClickListener(IItemClickListener iItemClickListener) {
        this.iItemClickListener = iItemClickListener;
    }

    public MyViewHolder (View itemView ){
        super(itemView);

        txt_item_titles= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        img_item= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

       itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        iItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
  }



 public class MyItemGroupAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemGroupAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<itemGroup> dataList;

public MyItemGroupAdapter(Context context, List<itemGroup> dataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
   View itemView = 
 LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_group,viewGroup,false);
   return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

    myViewHolder.item_title.setText(dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle());

    List<itemData> itemData = dataList.get(i).getListItem();

    MyItemAdapter itemListAdapter=new MyItemAdapter(context,itemData);
    myViewHolder.recycler_view_item_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    myViewHolder.recycler_view_item_list.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    myViewHolder.recycler_view_item_list.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);

    myViewHolder.recycler_view_item_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


    // btn more

    myViewHolder.btn_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button More "+ myViewHolder.item_title.getText(), 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (dataList != null ? dataList.size() : 0);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView item_title ;
    RecyclerView recycler_view_item_list;
    Button btn_more;

    public MyViewHolder (View itemView ){
        super (itemView);
        item_title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        btn_more= (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btMore);
        recycler_view_item_list= 
 (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Hi. I really do not know where the problem is. Thank

Comment: I gave my best guess below, but I **strongly** recommend reading the link that Alex gave as it gives concrete guidance on how to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to have a structure like this in the database:

```
"list": {
  "-Nasdueqriyew": "First value",
  "-Nberqiy39esd": "Second value",
  "-Nc3hadsiuhad": "Third value"
}
```

And then try to map it to a `List` or array in your Java class.

The JSON structure is not a list, because it was pairs of keys and values, which in Java translates to:

```
Map<String, Object>
```

So most likely, the `List<itemData>` in your code needs to be a `Map<String, itemData>`.